# The 500 men killed in Shushan, and the 500 Jews who killed Amaleki

Tags: number, parshanut-torah-comment, amalek

Is there a source to connect (mystically, or otherwise) those enemies of the Jews (presumably Amaleki) killed in Megillas [Esther 9:12](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt3309.htm#12) with the 500 men from the tribe of Shimon who killed out the remainder of the Amaleki in [Divrei Hayamim I 4:42-43](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt25a04.htm#42)?

Comment: If there isn't, there should be.

Comment: you can read this doc(hebrew) from harab reoven rivlin its connect all the wars againts amalek, http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CGwQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.kbymedia.org%2Fuploads%2Ftext%2Fmoadim%2Fpurim%2Fpurim023.doc&ei=3a-rT-2fA5DSsgam-riHBQ&usg=AFQjCNHwNg2J1AXUc3D5L8bjXqzP6GO2Ig

Answer (score 4):

[The shiur](http://www.filefactory.com/file/7gdq80su0oxb/n/Drasha_Purim_RCK_-Purim_2012_mp3) that [was referenced](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/16741) states that the reishish chochma says that Mordechia donned sak (sackcloth) which is gematria 400 to counteract Eisav (who attacks the Jews with 400 men). The sak leads to tzayis (listening) which is gematria 500.  The magid shiur then pairs this with the pasuk (in ki sisa) kach lecha besamim mor dror (mordechai) chamesh meos (500). This all parallels the 500 people killed by the Jews in shushan.

He doesn't mention anything about Shimon and those 500 men but it would fit very well with what he was saying (someone should tell him). Especially because Shimon is related to shmiyah (listening)

Comment: vram, thanks for your answer, and welcome to Mi Yodeya. I hope you stick around and enjoy the site.

Answer (score 0):

Listen to this shiur which discusses this idea: http://www.filefactory.com/file/7gdq80su0oxb/n/Drasha_Purim_RCK_-Purim_2012_mp3

Comment: A summary would be nice.

Comment: What @DoubleAA said. Plus bibliographic information (who spoke?).

Comment: It's a recording of me speaking at my Purim Seudah